# where can I find the data sent from kafka to elasticSearch ? knowing that I using a ElasticSearch sink?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, apache-kafka-connect

This my output. I think that everything works fine:

```
[2018-07-06 22:27:51,458] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=connect-elk-sink] Setting newly assigned partitions [elk-test-0] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2018-07-06 22:27:51,471] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=connect-elk-sink] Resetting offset for partition elk-test-0 to offset 0. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher)
```

how I could visualize the data in Kibana?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Elasticsearch REST API directly to hit the index that you set up in your Connect Config, or the `/_cat`  endpoint, I believe.

However, Kibana would be easier as a visualization. Before you can do anything in Kibana, you must setup an Index Pattern via the Settings panel, and it'll prompt for a time field which can be ignored if you don't have one, but you can then go to the Discover panel and query the data as needed.

If no index pattern is created, then Connect either doesn't have permissions to do so, or there is no data flowing, or some other error.

Your log output is not an indication things are actually working, as it's simply saying that the consumer offset has been reset to the beginning of the Kafka partition